# Where does MplayerX keep its playback history?

Tags: mplayer

MplayerX, not only remembers what I've watched but also is able to resume playback at a later invocation.

For example, if I watch media-file abc.m4v for 4 minutes and then quit the program.  Then start MplayerX at a later date and open abc.m4v, it starts playback at 4 minutes.

I'd like to know where it stores the playback history.  I'd also like to know if I can retrieve that information.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MPlayerX saves playback positions in plist file `~/Library/Application Support/MPlayerX/bookmarks.plist`

Comment: Thank you for this!  Do you know what the values stand for.  I see things like<key> file://localhost/abc.m4v </key><string>33.795867</string> What does 33.795867 stand for?