# MplayerX playback positions

Tags: mplayer

MplayerX, not only remembers what I've watched but also is able to resume playback at a later invocation.

As stated [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/85984/where-does-mplayerx-keep-its-playback-history) "MPlayerX saves playback positions in plist file ~/Library/Application Support/MPlayerX/bookmarks.plist"

Can someone please explain what the values in the plist file mean?

```
<key> file://localhost/abc.m4v </key>
<string>33.795867</string>
```

clearly one is the name of the file but what does the numerica value signify?  How can I translate 33.79... to something meaningful like "70% viewed" or "50 minutes viewed".

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tested it, it is the number of seconds from the beginning of the video.